# How I can deinstall OSS-LINUX audio drivers?

Tags: sound, 17.04, oss

Ass official documentation says:

```
DEB Package: 
dpkg –purge oss-linux
```

I need to run this command through tty console, but when I run it, it gives me error.

```
Erorr: unknown option -u
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should execute the command on this way ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dpkg.1.html)):

```
dpkg –-purge oss-linux
```

You miss one dash (-). Or you can use this way:

```
dpkg –P oss-linux
```

`--purge` is other variant of `-P`